# A possible characterization of the category of finite $p$-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\mathcal{FG}$ be the category of finite groups. Let $S$ be a full subcategory of $\mathcal{FG}$.
Assume that $G\in \mathcal{FG}$ and $P\in S$ is a subgroup of $G$. We say that $P$ is $S$-maximal if there is no object $P'\in S$ with $P\subset P' \subset G$. Assume that $S$ satisfies the following conditions:

1. The subcategory $S$ is closed under taking subgroups, taking extensions" and isomorphy. That is: $P\in S, Q\subset P$ implies that $Q \in S$. Moreover for every short exact sequence $1\to P\to Q\to R\to 1$ we have $Q\in S$ if $P,R \in S$. Moreover every group isomorphic to an object of $S$ lies in $S$.
2. For every $G\in \mathcal{FG}$, every two $S$-maximal subgroups of $G$ are conjugate. Moreover for every maximal $S$-subgroup $P$  of $G\in \mathcal{FG}$ we have $N(N(P))=N(P)$ and  $\lvert G\rvert/\lvert N(P)\rvert$ is coprime to $|P|$.

Does it imply that $S$ is the category of $p$-groups for some prime number $p$?

Comment: "$|G|/N(P)$ is coprime to $|G|$"?

Comment: @JeremyRickard I am really sorry I revise it.

Comment: @YCor Thank you for your revision

Comment: You probably want to rule out the trivial cases where $S$ consists of trivial groups or of all finite groups.

Comment: The three conditions in (1) can be collapsed to just: for every exact sequence $P \to Q \to R$, we have that $Q \in S$ if $P, R \in S$.  (Oh, maybe you have to add the assumption that the trivial group belongs to $S$.)

Comment: Actually there's nothing categorical in the question, which is about a certain subclass of the class of finite groups.

Comment: @LSpice It seems to me you’ve just restated the closure under extensions condition, which does imply the closure under isomorphy condition, but not the closure under subgroups condition I think.

Comment: @YCor I agree that there is no formal reliance on category theory. But I think it’s fair to say that the closure conditions on $S$ are naturally motivated and thought about from a categorical perspective. (Perhaps you were replying to a since-deleted comment and I’m missing some context, in which case my apologies)

Comment: @TimCampion, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372094/a-possible-characterization-of-the-category-of-finite-p-groups#comment941157_372094), given the containment $Q \subseteq R$ with $R \in S$, we have $R \to 1 \to R$, so use [the condition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372094/a-possible-characterization-of-the-category-of-finite-p-groups#comment941058_372094) once to conclude from $R \in S$ that $1 \in S$; and then $1 \to Q \to R$, and so use it again to conclude from $P, R \in S$ that $Q \in S$.

Comment: @LSpice Oh I see -- you don't require your exact sequences to be short exact! I'm a little hazy on what the definition of an "exact sequence" ought to be in a category like $Grp$ where not every monomorphism is regular, but I suppose that makes sense. On the other hand, your condition would also imply that $S$ is closed under quotients, which we didn't need to assume.

Comment: @TimCampion, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372094#comment941177_372094), I thought: $A \xrightarrow i B \xrightarrow j C$ is exact if $j \circ i$ factors through $1 \to C$ and if $\operatorname{im}(i) \to \ker(j)$ is an isomorphism. (I state it that way because I think it fits into a more general framework, but I'm no category theorist.) You're right about quotients; I first read the closure condition in (1) as:  given $1 \to P \to Q \to R \to 1$, we have $Q \in S$ if *and only if* $P, R \in S$. I eventually realised that's not what it said, but forgot about that when re-stating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can get most of the way to an answer, without using all the conditions.

**Definition:**  Say that $S \subseteq \mathcal{FG}$ is *nice* if it is nonempty and closed under subgroups, extensions, and isomorphy, and has the property that for any $G \in \mathcal{FG}$, the $S$-maximal subgroups of $G$ are all conjugate.

**Proposition:** Suppose that $S \subseteq \mathcal{FG}$ is nice. Then there is a set $\mathcal P$ of primes such that $P \in S$ if and only if the prime divisors of $|P|$ are all in $\mathcal P$.

This implies that any [$\mathcal P$-Hall subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_subgroup) of $G$ is a maximal $S$-subgroup of $G$. Conversely, if $G$ has a maximal $S$-subgroup $H$, then assuming niceness, since $H$ contains the Sylow $p$-subgroups for each $p \in \mathcal P$, we have that $H$ is a $\mathcal P$-Hall subgroup. That is, if $S$ is nice, then a maximal $S$-subgroup is precisely a Hall $\mathcal P$-subgroup.

**Proof:** Let $\mathcal P$ be the set of primes $p$ such that there exists $P \in S$ with $p$ dividing $|P|$ (as it must be). By passing to subgroups, we have $C_p \in S$ for $p \in \mathcal P$, and by taking extensions we have that every finite $p$-group is in $S$ for every $p \in \mathcal P$. Let $G$ be a finite group such that the prime divisors of $|G|$ are in $\mathcal P$. Now, there are $S$-maximal subgroups of $G$ containing each Sylow subgroup of $G$, and by hypothesis these are all conjugate and in particular have the same order. So if $|G| = p^n m$ with $p$ not dividing $m$, then $p^n$ divides the order of any $S$-maximal subgroup $P \subseteq G$. Since this is true for all prime divisors $p$ of $|G|$, we have that $|G|$ divides $|P|$, so that $P = G$, and thus $G \in S$.

---

It's known that not all $\mathcal P$-Hall subgroups of a finite group $G$ are conjugate in general, but I don't happen to know whether the known counterexamples cover all possible sets $\mathcal P$ of primes other than the subsingletons and the set of all primes. If $G$ is solvable, then its $\mathcal P$-Hall subgroups *are* conjugate -- so if we replace $\mathcal{FG}$ with just the solvable finite groups we get an expanded set of possibilities for $S$.

---

(Many of the comments relate to an earlier version of this post which attempted to whittle down the set of $\mathcal P$ allowed. Thanks to Richard Lyons below for pointing out the mistake.)

---

**EDIT:** I just wanted to add another way to close the argument, alternate to Richard Lyons' above, which relies on the original literature on Hall subgroups.

Hall showed in [Theorems Like Sylow's](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-6.2.286), discussion after Theorem A4, that if $\mathcal P$ contains two primes smaller than $n$, then any Hall $\mathcal P$-subgroup of $\Sigma_n$ cannot be solvable. Then Thompson showed in [Hall subgroups of the symmetric groups](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(66)80032-7) that the only nonsolvable Hall subgroups of $\Sigma_n$ are the trivial group, $\Sigma_n$ itself, and (if $n$ is prime) $\Sigma_{n-1}$. So if $\mathcal P$ contains $p,q$ and omits $r$, then take $G = \Sigma_n$ for any composite $n > p,q,r$. The only candidate Hall subgroups of $G$ are the trivial group and $G$ itself; the former is not a $\mathcal P$-Hall subgroup because $p | n!$ and the latter is not because $r | n!$.

Comment: Why does your condition $\operatorname{trace}(x y) = 2\Re(\zeta_r)$ imply that $x y$ has order $r$?

Comment: @LSpice the determinant is 1 so the trace determines the characteristic polynomial, and hence the eigenvalues must be $\zeta_r,\bar \zeta_r$

Comment: [Thanks](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372094/a-possible-characterization-of-the-category-of-finite-p-groups#comment941155_372110)!  Why are distinct eigenvalues needed?  If all you care about is the order, then it seems to me that $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ is as good an order-$2$ element as any.

Comment: @LSpice I'm using distinct eigenvalues simply to ensure that the matrix is diagonalizable -- the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ has the same characteristic polynomial as $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ but doesn't even have finite order! We can avoid talking about eigenvalues by observing here that the characteristic polynomial $(z+1)^2$ doesn't divide the polynomial $z^2 - 1$, so doesn't ensure that that $z$ has order 2.

Comment: Let me try to say it once and for all, cleanly. If $M \in SL_2(\mathbb C)$, then its characteristic polynomial is $p(z) = z^2 - \operatorname{trace}(M)z + 1$. The fact is that for any $r \in \mathbb N_{\geq 3}$, if $\operatorname{trace}(M) = 2 \Re(\zeta_r)$, then $p(z)$ divides the $r$th cyclotomic polynomial, and so $M$ has order $r$; if $r = 2$, then $p(z)$ only divides the _square_ of the $r$th cyclotomic polynomial, so we can't conclude this. In order to see this fact, I tend to think in terms of eigenvalues and Jordan normal forms, but the fact can be stated without referring to these.

Comment: [Got it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372094/a-possible-characterization-of-the-category-of-finite-p-groups/372110#comment941206_372110), thanks (and sorry for the several questions).  (I wonder if the unipotent element you mention *can* be written as a product of two finite-order elements?  It's probably straightforward to see either way, but it's not obvious to me.)

Comment: No, thanks for the questions! Especially because I was still confused myself.

Comment: @LSpice It occurs to me that since that matrix is in $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, and since $PSL(2,\mathbb Z) = C_2 \ast C_3$ (I forget the exact generators), and since the kernel of $SL(2,\mathbb Z) \to PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$ is torsion, it follows that it _can_ be written as a product of finite-order elements. But I don't know if two of them suffice!

Comment: @TimCampion Is the reduction correct to just finding $x$ and $y$? For example, let $P=\{3,5\}$ and $G=SL_2(16)$, of order $2^4.3.5.17$. Then $G$ has a cyclic subgroup $H$ of order $15$ and any subgroup of $G$ of order dividing $15$ is conjugate  to a subgroup of $H$. (Theorem. If a group has a nilpotent Hall $P$-subgroup $A$, then any $P$-subgroup of it is conjugate to a subgroup of $A$.) But $G$ contains $SL_2(4)\cong A_5$ and so it contains $x$ of order $3$ and $y$ of order $5$ such that $xy$ has order $2$.

Comment: @RichardLyons Thanks, I'm definitely out on a limb here, not really being a finite group theorist -- so I'm really glad to look at an actual example! And I think you're absolutely right -- Let $S$ be defined by $\mathcal P = \{3,5\}$ and let $G,H$ be as you defined them; if we assume that $S$ is nice, then we can conclude that every $x \in G$ of order 3 is contained in a subgroup isomorphic to $H$ and similarly for every $y \in G$ of order 5, but we can't conclude that for every such $x,y$ that they are both contained in the _same_ copy of $H$, which is what my argument wrongly assumed.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the initial answer to the question is equivalent to the following assertion: *for all distinct primes $p,q,r$, there exists a finite group $G$ such that every subgroup of $G$ of index coprime to $pq$ possesses an element of order $r$*.

Answer (score 7):

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\newcommand\card[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}$Here is a proof of "yes," using Tim Campion's proposition [below](https://mathoverflow.net/a/372110).

Let $p$ be the smallest prime in $P$. For any prime $q\ne p$, let $o_q(p)$ be the multiplicative order of $p$ modulo $q$, or equivalently the least $n$ such that $q$ divides $\card{\GL_n(p)}$. Assuming $P\ne\{p\}$, let $q\in P-\{p\}$ and $G=\GL(V)$ where $V$ is a vector space of order $p^n$ and $n=o_q(p)$. As $p$ is smallest, $n\ge2$. By assumption, $G$ contains a [Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_subgroup) $P$-subgroup $X$. Then $X$ contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup $U$ of $G$ as well as an element $x$ of order $q$. If $U$ is normal in $X$, then $\card X$ divides $\card U(p-1)^n$, the order of the full upper triangular group, which is not divisible by $q$ as $q>p$. So $U$ is not normal in $X$. The theory of $B$-$N$ pairs then implies that $X$ contains a copy of $\operatorname{SL}_2(p)$. Hence every prime divisor of $p-1$ lies in $P$, which forces $p=2$. Then $U$ is a Borel subgroup of $G$, so $X$ must be a parabolic subgroup of $G$. But because of $x$, $X$ stabilizes no proper subspace of $V$. The only such parabolic subgroup is $X=G$. Hence $P$ contains all prime divisors of $\card G$.
In particular, $3\in P$.

Now suppose that $P$ is not the set of all primes and choose a prime $r\not\in P$ to minimize $m=o_r(2)$.  Since $3\in P$, $m\ge3$. Let $H=\GL(W)$, where $W$ is a vector space of order $2^m$. Then $H$ contains an element $y$ of order $r$. Let $U$ be a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $H$. Let $W_1$ and $W_{m-1}$ be $U$-invariant subspaces of $W$ of respective dimensions $1$ and $m-1$. Let $H_1$ and $H_{m-1}$ be their respective stabilizers in $H$. Then $H_1$ and $H_{m-1}$ are maximal parabolic subgroups of $H$ containing $U$, and each is an extension of an elementary abelian $2$-group by $\GL_{m-1}(2)$. Hence $H_1$ and $H_{m-1}$ are $P$-groups, by our choice of $r$. However, they are maximal subgroups of $H$ and they are not conjugate in $H$, being distinct parabolic subgroups containing $U$.

By assumption, $\langle H_1^g, H_{m-1}\rangle$ must be a $P$-group for some $g\in H$. Since $H_{m-1}$ is maximal and not equal to $H_1^g$, $H$ must be a $P$-group. But $y\in H$ has order $r\notin P$, contradiction.